# Configurable state with Zustand and Router

Tags: reactjs, zustand

I have a `<Highlight>` component that renders text highlights. Currently, it takes a [Zustand store](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/) as a prop (but I would like to move that store inside the component). Let's call this `storeA`.

There are many types of highlights; I want to be able to "plug these in" on a per-usage basis, like `<Highlight kinds={[red, blue]}>` in one place and `<Highlight kinds={[red, green]}>` in another. (I'm using props for illustration; my question is about how I should structure the API, and props may not be the answer.) I need to do this

- without breaking the rules of Hooks; so I should be able to do `<Highlight kinds={kinds}>` and change the length of `kinds` without breaking things
- without centralizing all the different kinds inside `<Highlight>`

The various kinds are computed in different ways:

- Red highlights are derived from the state of `storeA`;
- Blue highlights are derived from the state of a different Zustand store `storeB`;
- Green highlights are derived from query parameters via `next/router`'s [`useRouter()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router)

What I'm currently doing is giving the Blue and Green highlight providers access to `storeA`, and doing something like

```
storeA.setState(prev => ({
  highlights: {
    ...prev.highlights,
    green: newGreenHighlights
  }
});
```

The main issue I'm having with this approach is that the Blue and Green providers need to call this `setState` in a `useEffect` or imperative event handler. I would prefer to have them derive state from a Hook call.

**What is a clean way to structure this API?**